# Why do I face missing plugin error when I run app in release mode?

Tags: flutter, dart, zegocloud

So I get this error E/flutter (13292): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getVersion on channel zego_zim_plugin) from zegocloud when I run app in release mode but works fine in debug mode. What could be the issue and how do I fix it. And yes I have done flutter clean, I have removed and added the package still no change.Please help